# Convert file to csv from bash with sed

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sed

I have a file with a few lines like this:

```
-host hostname.domain.com -os "gpl x86_64 linux-5.3.18-24.52-default" -core A.10.20 -corepatch A.10.20 -ts_core A.10.20 -ts_corepatch A.10.20 -da A.10.20 -dapatch A.10.20
```

I would like to convert it in the shell to a file with tabs with just the first 2 fields and skip everything else:

```
hostname.domain.com     gpl x86_64 linux-5.3.18-24.52-default
```

Maybe with sed? I suck with these commands.

Comment: What does _convert from shell_ supposed to mean? _shell_ is not a file format.

Comment: Are there a lot of lines to process? This seems at first glance line something I'd just do manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with cut/awk. Here is example with cut:

```
[user@host~]$ echo '-host hostname.domain.com -os "gpl x86_64 linux-5.3.18-24.52-default" -core A.10.20 -corepatch A.10.20 -ts_core A.10.20 -ts_corepatch A.10.20 -da A.10.20 -dapatch A.10.20' | cut -d " "  -f2,4,5,6
hostname.domain.com "gpl x86_64 linux-5.3.18-24.52-default"
```

cut -d " " will use " " as delimeter and print fields in -f flag.

And to remove ", you can use tr.

```
tr -d "\""
```

Comment: Yep, i already done the cut part with  cat file | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat your_file | awk '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $2 }'
```

Awk might do it: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Awk is super versatile with this kind of thing, particularly because it can leverage the amazing `printf`.

Comment: Thanks, i got it:
awk '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $2, $4$5$6 }' | sed 's/"//'